# Differential one-forms and change of coordinates

Tags: analysis, differential-forms

Consider two differential one forms:

$$\omega=\sum_{i=1}^N \omega_i dx^i$$
$$\omega'=\sum_{i=1}^N \omega'_i dx'^i$$

As I recall from my analysis courses, the symbols $dx$ are a particular notation for  specific dual basis. It now makes sense to define the equality $\omega=\omega'$ if and only if

$$<\omega,v>=<\omega', Mv> \forall v \in \mathbb{R}^N$$

Where $M$ is the matrix that changes from the canonical basis to the basis given by the isomorphism $v^i_k = dx'^i_k$, $k=1,...,N$  (this is all speculation since we haven't covered change of coordinates with one-forms, so please correct me if I'm wrong). Is it now possible to have more general change of coordinates, namely non-linear ones? How do one forms transform under those?

EDIT: For those of you who don't dislike physics, I need this for a proof on canonical transformations of the Hamiltonians. Namely, we are supposing we have two one forms which, by hypothesis, are claimed to be equal up to an exact differential.

$$pdq-H(p,q,t)dt=PdQ-K(P,Q,t)dt+dF(P,Q,t)$$

I had a hard time interpreting the equality, since I didn't know how to interpret the $dQ$ symbol (better: I had an idea, that is taking the differential of the change of coordinates and substituting, this post is mainly for confirmation and for learning something a bit more general).

Comment: I'm a bit confused, in the edit are you looking for a proof of a Legendre transformation?

Comment: No. The claim is that the two one forms are equal up to an exact differential if and only if the trajectories that are stationary to the action are equal. This is, as I understand, one way to characterize  canonical transformations: the existence of a "generating function", that is the function whose differential is in the equation which I have written above. The two one forms generate from the principle of least action.

Comment: Here's a better way to think of this: Exact $1$-forms are characterized (either locally or in a simply connected space, which is, I believe your setting) by having their integrals around closed loops all be $0$. Now, you have expressions in terms of coordinates $(p,q,t)$ and $(P,Q,t)$. You should think of a change of coordinates mapping (diffeomorphism) which gives $(P,Q,t) = F(p,q,t)$ and calculate the pullback $F^*(PdQ-K(P,Q,t)dt)$. Now you're just working in $(p,q,t)$ coordinates.

Comment: Great, thank you. Since we haven't covered pullbacks either, I decided to momentarily divert from analytical mechanics and study some basics on differential forms since they appear to be useful beyond this. And I was wasting a lot of time trying to understand what my professor was saying.